# Can I write a function to open a new page and display only filtered divs?

Tags: javascript, html, css

Basically I have my main page with links () and a second page with multiple divs. Each div on the second page has a data-filter attribute. Is it possible to click the link on the main page and open the second page displaying only the filtered result?

In the example below the second link would open a page displaying only divs 3,4 and 5. etc...

```
#Main Page
<div>
<a href="second-page.html?sweet">Sweet</a>
<a href="second-page.html?sour">Sour</a>
<a href="second-page.html?bitter">Bitter</a>
<a href="second-page.html?savoury">Savoury</a>
</div>

#Second page

<div data-filter="sweet">1</div>
<div data-filter="bitter">2</div>
<div data-filter="bitter sour">3</div>
<div data-filter="sour">4</div>
<div data-filter="savoury sour">5</div>
<div data-filter="savoury">6</div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, it is possible with a little bit change in your design, and add a some css style and JavaScript, it is possible to achieve what you want.

First, I suggest made slight change on your main page so that it will be easier to get the query string later:

```
#Main Page
<div>
<a href="second-page.html?t=sweet">Sweet</a>
<a href="second-page.html?t=sour">Sour</a>
<a href="second-page.html?t=bitter">Bitter</a>
<a href="second-page.html?t=savoury">Savoury</a>
</div>
```

Then on your second page, I would suggest to change the attributes from `data-filter` to `class` as it is easier to be targeted and manipulated by JavaScript, then add the css style and Javascript:

```
<head>
  <style>
    .taste {display: none; }
    .show {display: block; }
  </style>
</head>
<body>
    <div class="taste sweet">1</div>
    <div class="taste bitter">2</div>
    <div class="taste bitter sour">3</div>
    <div class="taste sour">4</div>
    <div class="taste savoury sour">5</div>
    <div class="taste savoury">6</div>
<script>
    (function () {
      // get the query string from url
      const params = new URLSearchParams(location.search);
      const query = params.get("t");    //get t=query_string
      // use the query string to select the related divs
      const taste = document.querySelectorAll(`.${query}`);
      for (let i = 0; i<taste.length; i++) {
        taste[i].classList.add("show");    // add css class to those divs
      }
    })();
  </script>
</body>
```

All the divs are set to `display:none` at initial, and use the query string to decide what div should be set to `.show` (i.e. make it visible dynamically based on query string).

Comment: You shouldn't add display: none to all div elements. Start with divs having another class that hides them and them add .show or remove .hide (for example)

Comment: @NoOorZ24 You are right, that's not the best practice. I modified the code to add a class to each div

Answer (score 0):

On the 2nd page make all the divs invisible to start with (i.e. style="display:none;)

Add some JavaScript to extract out the URL param (i.e. var dataFilter = (document.URL.split).split("?").pop();)

Now use that dataFilter variable to get all the DIV's that have it as an attribute (i.e. document.querySelectorAll("[data-filter=dataFilter]") )

Now just cycle through the elements returned and make them visible ..